# Build types and flavours in multi module android application

Tags: android, module, gradle-kotlin-dsl, android-build-type

I have a multi module android application. I have core modules (network, data, database etc), data modules and feature modules. How should I handle the build types in the different `build.gradle.kts` files? If i don't copy paste buildTypes to all module's gradle file the app won't build. How can I inherit or something? What is the best practice to it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin DSL isn't as simplest as Gradle, because all it's typed so that "magic trick" with another Gradle script doesn't work here.

The solution is create a Gradle plugin and apply it to all of your modules.
First create a `buildSrc` folder in the root of your project, then in the root of `buildSrc` create `build.gradle.kt` with this content:

```
plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
}

repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:<your-gradle-version>")
}

gradlePlugin {
    plugins {
        register("base-configuration-plugin") { // Your custom plugin name
            id = "base-configuration-plugin" // Your custom plugin name
            implementationClass = "BaseConfigurationPlugin" // The class where your plugin is located.
        }
    }
}
```

After that, you will need to create your custom plugin implementation, in `buildSrc/main/java/BaseConfigurationPlugin.kt`

```
class BaseConfigurationPlugin : Plugin<Project> {
    override fun apply(target: Project) {
        val extension = target.extensions.getByName("android")
        if (extension is ApplicationExtension) {
            extension.setBuildFlavors()
        }
        if(extension is LibraryExtension){
            extension.setBuildFlavors()
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, "setBuildFlavors" doesn't exist, is just an extension method created to make it look more "kotlin style" here is the method.

```
private fun ApplicationExtension.setBuildFlavors() {
    flavorDimensions("version", "other_dimension")
    productFlavors {
        create("dev") {
            dimension = "version"
            applicationIdSuffix = ""
            versionNameSuffix = ""
        }
        create("production") {
            dimension = "version"
            applicationIdSuffix = ""
            versionNameSuffix = ""
        }
        create("pro") {
            dimension = "other_dimension"
            applicationIdSuffix = ""
            versionNameSuffix = ""
        }
        create("noob") {
            dimension = "other_dimension"
            applicationIdSuffix = ""
            versionNameSuffix = ""
        }
    }
}

// Same but for libraries
private fun LibraryExtension.setBuildFlavors(){
    flavorDimensions("version", "other_dimension")
    productFlavors {
        create("dev") { dimension = "version" }
        create("production") { dimension = "version" }
        create("pro") { dimension = "other_dimension" }
        create("noob") { dimension = "other_dimension" }
    }
}
```

And you are ready to apply the plugin!! Just put in all of your module's `build.gradle.kts`  and it should works like a charm!

```
plugins {
    `base-configuration-plugin`
}
```

[Here](https://medium.com/maibornwolff/android-app-modularization-with-kotlin-dsl-and-koin-193fc0ad0f7b) is an article where you can get more info. :)

Comment: Elegant! Does this solution handle merging too? What happens if I, in one of my modules' build.gradle.kts file, define one of the built types, say "pro", with either extensive or conflicting configuration? Will the plugin take that into consideration?

Comment: That is a good question, i don't have any project with that kind of configuration. Do you have one? It would be good if you try it!.